# MySQL not equals?

Tags: mysql, sql

In my query I specify..

```
SELECT field X, Y, Z 
FROM customer_table 
WHERE X = 10 
AND Y = "test"
```

This will return 5 records.
Now I need to add Z not equals to certain values.

If I add this:

```
AND Z != ID1 OR ID2
```

Then it returns me all values, ignoring the first criterias.
How can I specify Z criteria not to equal ID1 or ID2 values, so it would return me only the ID3, ID4 and ID5 values as results?

Comment: It is because the OR creates a condition that ignores the rest.  You can either use IN (as per Sager's answer) OR encapsulate the Z in brackets, i.e. AND (Z != ID1 OR Z != ID2)

Comment: Group the condition using brackets

SELECT field X, Y, Z 
FROM customer_table 
WHERE X = 10 
AND Y = "test"
AND ( Z!='ID1' or Z!='ID2')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT field X, Y, Z 
FROM customer_table 
WHERE X = 10 
AND Y = "test"
AND  Z NOT IN( ID1,ID2)
```

Try above code.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: alternatively you can use Z <> ID1 OR z <> ID2
but sagar example is the better way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
SELECT field X, Y, Z 
FROM customer_table 
WHERE (X = 10 AND Y = "test") 
AND WHERE NOT (Z = ID1 OR Z = ID2)
```

It should be work ;)

Answer (score 0):

`Group` the  condition using brackets

```
SELECT field X, Y, Z 
FROM customer_table 
WHERE X = 10 
AND Y = "test"
AND ( Z!=ID1 or Z!=ID2)
```